# d3.js word cloud load data from json

Tags: json, d3.js

I'm modifying this code https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud to display the "keywords" from a json file.

My Questions: 
How to connect the json file to display the keywords tags?
Is it possible to highlight words (bigger font for instance) which are more common?

Thank you guys!

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script src="../lib/d3/d3.js"></script>
<script src="../d3.layout.cloud.js"></script>
<script>
var fill = d3.scale.category20();

d3.layout.cloud().size([300, 300])
  .words([
    "Hello", "world", "normally", "you", "want", "more", "words",
    "than", "this"].map(function(d) {
    return {text: d, size: 10 + Math.random() * 90};
  }))
  .padding(5)
  .rotate(function() { return ~~(Math.random() * 2) * 90; })
  .font("Impact")
  .fontSize(function(d) { return d.size; })
  .on("end", draw)
  .start();

function draw(words) {
d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 300)
    .attr("height", 300)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(150,150)")
  .selectAll("text")
    .data(words)
  .enter().append("text")
    .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.size + "px"; })
    .style("font-family", "Impact")
    .style("fill", function(d, i) { return fill(i); })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
    })
    .text(function(d) { return d.text; });
 }
 </script>
```

**pub.json**

```
{"pub":[
    {
        "citationKey":"Smuc_HCV2012",
        "entryType":"inbook",
        "entryTags": {
            "title":"How do you connect moving dots? Insights from user studies on Dynamic Network Visualizations",
            "booktitle":"Handbook of Human Centric Visualization",
            "year":"2013",
            "pages":"623-650",
            "publisher":"Springer",
            "organization":"Springer",
            "location":"New York, USA",
            "isbn":"978-1-4614-7484-5",
            "doi":"10.1007/978-1-4614-7485-2_25",
            "type":"Awesome Reports",
            "author":"muc, Michael and Federico, Paolo and Windhager, Florian and Aigner, Wolfgang and Zenk, Lukas and Miksch, Silvia",
            "editor":"Huang, Weidong"
            "keywords":"Data Mining, KDD, Pattern Finding, Time-Oriented Data, Visual analytics"
            }
    },
    {
        "citationKey":"Schratt_2009_IKE-TR-2009-02_UmfragezuBusiness-Intelligence-Weiterbildung",
        "entryType":"incollection",
        "entryTags": {
            "title":"Umfrage zu Business-Intelligence-Weiterbildung",
            "number":"IKE-TR-2009-02",
            "year":"2009",
            "publisher":"Danube University Krems",
            "type":"Technical Reports",
            "author":"Schratt, Alexander and Aigner, Wolfgang"
            "keywords":"Data Mining, Interactive Visualization, KDD, Pattern Finding, temporal   data mining, Time-Oriented Data, Visual analytics"
            }
    }


    ]
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

- How to connect the json file to display the keywords tags?

Host the file on your server. Let's say it's at `/resources/pub.json`. Then get it to client with `d3.json` for example. You can then use the data you retrieved as input for the wordcloud.

```
d3.json('/resources/pub.json', function(error, data){

    // get words as a list of objects of the form {text: 'asdf', size: 5}
    // ie. 

    words = data.pub[0]['entryTags']['title'].split(' '); // now its a list of words in the title
    words = words.map(function(word){
        return {
          text: word,
          size: 12
        }
    }); // now it has the correct format, but this is just an example

    // then use it as input to the layout
    d3.layout.cloud().size([300, 300])
     .words(words)
     ... // etcetera

});
```

- Is it possible to highlight words (bigger font for instance) which are more common?

Yes, the size is set in this line:

```
.enter().append("text")
.style("font-size", function(d) { return d.size + "px"; })
.. // etcetera
```

So if you make sure your words get different sizes, for example through counting occurences in the previous transformation, they have different sizes.

There are also many different approaches

- You may include the data in the javascript directly, so you don't have to request it from the server 
  separately
- You can transform the data into the correct format on the server, so you don't have to do the transformation clientside.
- Instead of text and size, you can use other formats for each tag in the cloud, for example adding `count` and `color`, and use those in the formatting.

Note that this is pseudocode to get you going, but it's not complete.